# How to say “I, John Smith, promise that …” ?

Tags: constructions

Is the following the correct thing to say in French?

> I, John Smith, promise that I will not work or carry out any professional
>   activities
>
> Je suis John Smith promesse que je ne vais pas travailler ou d'exercer toute
>   activité professionnelle

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are writing an affidavit for a visa or something like that, one could write

> Je soussigné, Michel Dupont, né le 18 juin 1940 à
>       Townsend (Royaume-Uni), m'engage à n'exercer aucune
>       activité professionnelle, rémunérée ou non, lors de
>       ce séjour en France.

But **of course** if this is a real legal question then you should get better help than some guy on the net answering a very unclear question. If you're applying for a visa then there's probably a boiler-plate phrase that you are supposed to copy and sign.

Answer (score 5):

An informal way to express this is:

> Moi, John Smith, (je) vous promets que …

The formal way (in written correspondance) is:

> Je soussigné, John Smith, promets que …

Meaning, literally, that your signature is present at the end of the document.

Comment: On ne "promet pas", dans un document formel (ou un contrat). Le terme normal est "je m'engage". Voir la réponse de Law29

Comment: @guillaume: Je ne fait que reprendre le terme employé dans la question. Qui existe… https://www.google.at/search?q="soussigné+promets"&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr&gws_rd=cr ne t'en déplaise. Et tu ne me fera pas utiliser *s'engager à ne pas faire quelque chose*, bien plus douteux.